# Still getting a 503 error when making API calls in my React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, axios, http-status-code-503

I am trying to get my React-Redux app to communicate to my deployed Heroku API via Axios.

When I try to make a POST request to my Heroku server via Axios I get this error message in my console in the Chrome developer tools:

[image]

As you can see in the screencap, I am getting "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." as well as error status code of 503.

And something I find rather odd is that my `/register` request is being fired twice. Is that normal?

[image]

Here is the configuration in my `app.js` file in my backend code to enable cross domain requests:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Origin,X-Auth,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json,x-auth,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    next();
});
```

And here is the Axios code that makes the API call to the server in my front-end:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function register(fields) {

  console.log('below are the fields');
  console.log(fields);

  return function action(dispatch) {

    let objArrSkills = Object.keys(fields.form_skills);
    let skillsArr = objArrSkills.map(function (value) {

      if (fields.form_skills[value] === true && fields.form_skills[value] !== undefined) {
        return value;
      }

    });

    let objArrArts = Object.keys(fields.form_arts);
    let artsArr = objArrArts.map(function (value) {
      if (fields.form_arts[value] === true && fields.form_arts[value] !== undefined) {
        return value;
      }
    });

    console.log('artsArr is...' + artsArr);
    console.log('skillsArs is...' + skillsArr);

    const request = axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: "https://jammr-backend.herokuapp.com/register",

      data: {
        firstName: fields.form_first_name,
        lastName: fields.form_last_name,
        email: fields.form_email,
        password: fields.form_password,
        skills: skillsArr,
        iWantToMake: artsArr,
        street: fields.form_address,
        city: fields.form_city,
        provinceState: fields.form_province,
        gender: fields.form_gender,
        imLookingFor: ['Acting', 'Drawing', 'Music', 'Writing', 'Programming', 'Videography']
      },

      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': "Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Origin,X-Auth,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json,x-auth,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS'
      }
    });

    return request.then(response => {
      console.log('axios call ran! Below is response....');
      console.log(response);
      dispatch({
        type: 'REGISTER',
        payload: {
          myId: response.data,
          fields: fields,
          skills: skillsArr,
          iWantToMake: artsArr
        }
      })
    },
      err => {
        if (err) throw err;
      })
  }
};
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Here is my [front-end](https://github.com/tarekgabarin/jammrFrontFinal/blob/master/src/actions/index_actions.js) and [back-end](https://github.com/tarekgabarin/jamrBackend/blob/master/app.js) code on Github.

And in case it's relevant, my backend is deployed on Heroku. Also, I did try using the cors npm package, but it didn't work.

Comment: have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I would be willing to bet you are getting the 503 from the heroku stack because of some issue with your backend. (A timeout perhaps?) Obviously, the Heroku stack is not going to add the cross origin headers which is why you are seeing the cross origin errors in the JS console. Can you perhaps post your server logs?